# Is aggressive treatment needed in inferior wall type of heart attacks

Tags: heart-disease, heart-attack, myocardial-infarction, coronary-bypass

Heart attack or myocardial infarction (MI) is broadly of 2 types: anterior wall and inferior wall, depending on the wall of heart involved. The anterior wall MI is far more dangerous, both in short and in long term, and hence aggressive treatment (like angiography, angioplasty, coronary bypass surgery) is indicated there. However, is aggressive treatment also indicated for patients with inferior type of heart attacks, where the prognosis is much better? Thanks for your responses.